# Can every prime be written as $2p-q$ where $p,q \in \mathbb{P}, p \neq q, p>3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Can every prime be written as $2p-q$ where $p,q \in \mathbb{P}, p \neq q, p>3$?

```
p,q     2p-q
---     ----
5,7     3
11,17   5
5,3     7
7,3     11
37,61   13
11,5    17
11,3    19
13,3    23
17,5    29
...     ...
```

Also, it seems each prime itself has infinitely many primes $p,q$ satisfying $2p-q$?

For example, let $2p-q=3$, then

```
p,q     
---     
5,7
7,11
11,19
13,23
17,31
23,43
31,59
37,71
41,79
43,83
53,103
67,131
71,139
83,163
97,191
101,199
...
```

Comment: Goldbach's Conjecture : every even counting number greater than 2 is equal to the sum of two prime numbers.

Comment: This seems to be a special case of Goldbach's conjecture.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2p-q=r$ where $p,q,r$ are a prime numbers

$r+q=2p=\text{an even number}$

It is a special case of Goldbach's conjecture

Goldbach's conjecture is one of the oldest and best-known unsolved problems in number theory and all of mathematics. It states that every even natural number greater than two is the sum of two prime numbers.

Comment: The conjecture says that all even numbers can be written as the sum of prime numbers, so this is different from that in that it asks whether $2p$ is always the sum of two primes, where $p$ is prime. So if this is a special case it may be provable. I don't know what "Hint:" is supposed to mean here.

Comment: So basically a "special case" means it's weaker than Goldbach's since I've restricted the statement to even numbers that are twice a prime. Thanks!

Comment: Goldbach's conjecture doesn't guarantee that an even number has more than one representation, and we already know $2p$ has one: $p+p$.

Comment: Also we're supposed to be given $r$, not $p$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of [Dickson's conjecture](https://primes.utm.edu/glossary/page.php?sort=DicksonsConjecture). Note that you must exclude the case $r=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hardy and Littlewood conjecture that the number of ways to write even number $N$ as a sum of two primes is asymptotic to
$$
\sim{2N\over\log^2N}\prod_{\substack{p|N\\p>2}}{p-1\over p-2}\prod_{p>2}\left(1-{1\over(p-1)^2}\right).
$$
As a result, if $p,p;$ denote primes. Then the number of ways to write $2p$ as a sum of two primes is conjectured to be about
$$
\sim{4p\over\log^2p}\prod_{p'>2}\left(1-{1\over(p'-1)^2}\right)
$$
as $p\to\infty$